# Deconstruct object gives QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread

Tags: c++, qt

My code is too long to post, here is the related part:

```
videoClass::videoClass()
{   
    ...
    QThread* workerThread = new QThread(this);
    camwrk = new cameraWorker(workerThread);
    camwrk->moveToThread(workerThread);
    // There are many cross thread signal slot connections happening between this and the camwrk
}

videoClass::~videoClass()
{   
    ...

    delete camwrk;
    ...
}

cameraWorker::cameraWorker(QThread* workerThread)
{
    _belongingThread = workerThread;
    ...
}

cameraWorker::cameraWorker(QThread* workerThread)
{
    _belongingThread = workerThread;
    ...
}

cameraWorker::~cameraWorker()
{
    _belongingThread->quit();
    _belongingThread->wait();
}
```

Everytime when the _belongingThread->wait(); is finished, I got the message:

```
QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread
```

What is happening here? I thought this is the correct way to use a QThread and finish it?

Comment: Did you move `camwrk` to the other thread?

Comment: Oh yes. It is moved to workerThread. Please see the edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QThread` object itself belongs to the main thread:

> It is important to remember that a `QThread` instance lives in the old thread that instantiated it, not in the new thread that calls `run()`.

Apparently, `QThread::wait()` is implemented via events. Since `cameraWorker` itself is running on `workerThread` and not on `videoClass`'s thread, you can't use it.

That being said, your current logic seems a little bit too complicated. You want to stop the thread when the `cameraWorker` gets destroyed, and you want to destroy the camera worker when its parent gets destroyed too:

```
QThread* workerThread = new QThread(this);

connect(camwrk, SIGNAL(destroyed()), workerThread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(this,   SIGNAL(destroyed()), camwrk,       SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

If you want to delete the `workerThread` after it's finished its execution simply connect `finished()` and `deleteLater()`:

```
connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()),
        workerThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

However, keep in mind that `~videoClass()` will call the destructor of `workerThread`. Make sure that the thread doesn't run anymore before the object gets destroyed, or simply remove `this` from `new QThread(this)` to prevent ownership.

Comment: But when I call the delete on camwrk, I found its deconstructor is working on the main thread? Or it is just NOT Ok to delete an object when it has been moved to another thread via delete call in the main thread? Which left me no choice but to connect a signal to camwrk's deleteLater() slot?

Comment: @Nyaruko: The usual thread-safety issues can occur. If `cameraWorker` has a member `data` and a slot `process()`, what will happen if it's currently processing `data` in `process()` but `data` gets deleted by `~cameraWorker`? However, you don't need a signal. You can use `QTimer::singleShot` with a `0` timeout instead.

Comment: so to *connect(workerThread,&finished,worker,&deleteLater)* and call *workerThread->quit();workerThread->wait();* at the parent QObject's deconstructor is the safest way?