# Cannot simply delete an object after it has been moved to another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

My original question is here:
[Deconstruct object gives QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741579/deconstruct-object-gives-qcoreapplicationsendevent-cannot-send-events-to-obj)

And I have seen many people saying that you cannot delete an QObject from the gui thread after it has been moved to a workerthread.

like this:

```
//In the GUI thread
QThread* workerThread = new QThread(this);
worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
...
//Still in the Gui thread but somewhere else
delete worker;//Is this wrong?
```

In this case, if I want to stop the *workerthread* when I need to destroy the *worker*, isn't my only option is to do something like:

```
connect(worerThread,&finished,worker,&deleteLater)?
...
//when I no longer need the worker & the worker thread
workerThread->quit();
workerThread->wait();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can and should use

```
//Still in the Gui thread but somewhere else
worker->deleteLater();
```

Then `worker` is deleted in the `workerThread`. Also it is not needed to stop `workerThread` then.

More information about [`QObject::deleteLater()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#deleteLater) is in the Qt Documentation.

Comment: So, it is not Ok to delete the {worker} from the GUI thread ? And how about the method I mentioned, is this also a safe way?

Comment: Deleting it using delete is dangerous. The object could be used by another thread at that specific moment (e.g. the event loop of `workerThread`).

Comment: Does you `workerThread` only execute this single task? If so, have a look at [Qt Concurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html). Then you do not need to delete anything.